# How to open a webpage sending POST data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, redirect, post

I've a php page that contain some html code. It's a confirmation page for user who register to the site, so, i want to show it only in case of effective registration (with no possibilty to access it from external).
For do that i've placed this condition at the beginning of confirmation.php

```
if (empty($_POST))
{header('location: registration.php');}
```

the rest of the file is:

```
<div id="logo"> <img src=my_logo_small_grey.png  height="60"/> </div>
<div id="msgConfirm">Thank You</div>
```

(by the way, it is a good solution?)

But staring from registration.php, how to launch/redirect to confirmation.php sending it POST params? Actually i've used AJAX:

```
url = "confirmation.php";
params = "ok"
ajaxReq.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
ajaxReq.open("POST", url, true);
```

But it seems that only execute the script (thought), with no effective redirection.. why?

Comment: No, that is not a good solution. I can place a form on my website, action set to your URL, and send it via POST … and your form will show. Go look up what a CSRF protection token is and how to implement it.

Comment: This article on tokens is good? http://forum.codecall.net/topic/58268-form-tokens-with-php/

Answer (score 0):

use `jQuery`

`$.post()` will be key to implementing your solution.

---

but looking more generally at your question, normally, the workflow is following

1. fill a form
2. send email
3. user clicks on email link
4. confirmation page is opened
5. check hash, validate user
6. log-in and redirect to success page

if you really-really need to hide access to success page, create one-time-usable tokens.

having `(!empty($_POST))` is not a "strong" way of limiting access to that site.

Comment: ok i want' to use tokens, but how? In what language are they avaible? where i can begin to realize how to use it?

Comment: Create a table token (id, name). Upon signup, create random string and insert in token table, then redirect to success page and pass token (name) as get param. In success page, check if token exists in token table. If does, present content of the success page and remove token from db. Thats it.

Answer (score 0):

sorry, I don't full understand the question, but I'll give a shot at helping.

First, if the rest of the file is that small then you could just put it in an if loop.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['yourpost']))
{
?>

<div id="logo"> <img src=my_logo_small_grey.png  height="60"/> </div>
<div id="msgConfirm">Thank You</div>

<?php
}
?>
```

You can also create a redirect by writing out Javascript like below:

```
<?php
echo "<script>location.href='".$redirecturl."'</script>";    
?>
```

Post data is usually sent to a different page where it is processed and then you are taken to another page showing confirmation.
This data can be retrieved by getting it from the database again.(If you are doing that)

If you do want to pass on POST data retrieved onto another page, then you could add it as GET variables to the link like so www.url.com/index.php?get=something

You could also store a session variable as $_SESSION['var']="something";
Remembering to start session_start(); at the beginning of the php pages using sessions.

Sorry, I am not that experienced so maybe someone else will give better help, hope this helps for now.